# how to implicitly transform an angular's resource request's url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angular-resource

I made a `Directory` resource using **angular-resource** module

```
app.factory('Directory', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/directories/:id', null, {
    touch: { method: 'TOUCH' }
});
```

I want to touch a fetched directory

```
Directory.get({id: 8}, function (d) {
  d.$touch();
});
```

Well the request is sent, no problem

[image: touched]

except the `id` is not used in the url.

If I change as

```
d.$touch({id: 8});
```

it works but this is not really neat, as `d` already represents a `Directory` object having an id. How should I change my resource to call `$touch` with implicit id?

**ps** : I heard about the transformRequest parameter of an action's property but I am not sure it allows to change the url of the request within.

Comment: Can you try defining your custom action as: `touch: { method: 'TOUCH', params: { id: '@id' } }` and see what happens?

Comment: this totally works, i'm amazed sometimes to think my problem will be hard to get resolved but then realize it was a matter of few chars... thks